# creating a new dataframe from 3 other dataframes but columns must have specific order without specifying the name of the columns

Tags: pandas, concatenation

Assume we have 3 dataframes named df1, df2, df3. Each of these dataframes have 100 rows and 15 columns. I want to create new dataframe that will have the first column of df1, then the first column of df2m then the first column of df3. then it will have the second column of df1 then the second column of df2 then the second column of df3 and so on until all 15 columns of each of the three dataframes are included. For example

```
df1 
A         B        C    ...  O
1         1        1         1
1         1        1         1
...      ...      ...        ...

df2
A         B        C    ...  O
2         2        2         2
2         2        2         2
...      ...      ...        ...

df3
A         B        C    ...  O
3         3        3         3
3         3        3         3
...      ...      ...        ...
```

The expected output should be something like the following

```
dfnew 
A_df1     A_df2    A_df3     B_df1    B_df2   B_df3 ...   O_df1    O_df2   O_df3
1         2        3         1         2        3         1         2        3 
1         2        3         1         2        3         1         2        3 
...      ...      ...        ...
```

My issue is that I cannot use the names of the columns to specify them. For example I know how to do it like this

```
# create a list of the dataframes
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

# concatenate the dataframes along the columns axis (axis=1)
dfnew = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)

# specify the column names for the new dataframe
column_names = ["column1", "column2", ..., "column15"]

# concatenate the dataframes along the columns axis (axis=1)
# and specify the column names for the new dataframe
dfnew = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, columns=column_names)
```

but I cannot use the column names because they will change everytime. Plus it seems like there could be a faster way that hard coding them by using the .loc function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Exmaple**

```
data1 = {'A': {0: 1, 1: 1}, 'B': {0: 1, 1: 1}, 'C': {0: 1, 1: 1}}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = df1.replace(1, 2).copy()
df3 = df1.replace(1, 3).copy()
```

`df1`

```
    A   B   C
0   1   1   1
1   1   1   1
```

`df2`

```
    A   B   C
0   2   2   2
1   2   2   2
```

`df3`

```
    A   B   C
0   3   3   3
1   3   3   3
```

---

**Code**

```
dfs = (pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1, keys=['df1', 'df2', 'df3'])
       .sort_index(level=1, axis=1).swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1))
```

`dfs`

```
    A           B           C
    df1 df2 df3 df1 df2 df3 df1 df2 df3
0   1   2   3   1   2   3   1   2   3
1   1   2   3   1   2   3   1   2   3
```

```
dfs.set_axis(dfs.columns.map('_'.join), axis=1)
```

```
    A_df1   A_df2   A_df3   B_df1   B_df2   B_df3   C_df1   C_df2   C_df3
0   1       2       3       1       2       3       1       2       3
1   1       2       3       1       2       3       1       2       3
```

Comment: Thank you very much that was really helpful and easy to understand!